# div with rounded sides and pointy corners

Tags: html, css

I am making a div and I want to make the sides rounded.The problem is that I don't want the corners to be rounded but pointy. Any suggestions?

Comment: A drawing might be necessary here.

Comment: What do you mean rounded sides?

Comment: The same effect that border-radius has without the corners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
like tv screen

#tv {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50% / 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
}
#tv:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5% / 50%;
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/arjun_chaudhary/LBaNY/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure I understand what you're asking for, but is it something like this?

[image]

You can achieve it by using two div's like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="inner">
       Here's some text
   </div>
</div>
```

Then you can simply add a background image to your "container" div or play with CSS. Here's what I used for the previous example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    border-radius: 80px;
    background-color: #d6d6d9;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
.inner {
    background-color: #d6d6d9;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

I would strongly recommend you to upload an image to clarify your request.